# Cannot show image by img.src

Tags: javascript

I have no idea why setting img.src with import is fine but when I pass the path to it doesn't work.

```
import mahjong_tiles from '../assets/mahjong_tiles/1man.png'

const displayTileArr = () => {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = mahjong_tiles ; //OK
    img.src = '../assets/mahjong_tiles/1man.png';  //NOT OK
    document.getElementById('display-hand').appendChild(img);   
}
```

Comment: can you share the resulted HTML with both methods ?

Comment: `import` involves  JavaScript files `*.js`, not images. Is that `import` from something else?

Comment: @medilies I tried to save the html with ctrl+S, but it seems not including the content for the images.

Comment: @zer00ne But I only have png files in that directory.

Comment: Using `ctrl + u` is better than saving

Comment: The HTML file and the image file are two different resources. The HTML noes not contain the image, it just refers to it.

Comment: @chrwahl that would at least lead to knowing if the value of `src` is valid

Comment: Not sure why its not letting me reply specifically to zer00ne but your statement is incorrect, import does not only apply to .js files. It applies to .css files, image files, etc. etc.

Comment: @medilies Same result as Ctrl+S. The html doesn't have the elements I made in it.

Comment: It may be a URL issue. try to reference your assets using an `asset` helper function or using absolute paths

Comment: @medilies I tried also, but is doesn't work.

Comment: @BrentHarris the only filetype I see mention [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) is `*.js`

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the answer. it seems the .default is essential function to convert the url.

```js
img.src = require('../assets/mahjong_tiles/1man.png').default;
```

Answer (score -1):

check the path again,
works fine for me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEqpA.png)